# replace substring for particular position in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table and want update query to update dob

```
------------
dob
------------
19101984
19111984
19071985
19081985
19101985
19121985
```

I want to remove sub string from `position 5` to `character length of 2` means in the result table will be  :

```
------------
dob
------------
191084
191184
190785
190885
191085
191285
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `regex_replace`:

```
select regexp_replace(dob::text, '(\d{4})\d{2}(\d{2})', E'\\1\\2')
from your_table;
```

For updating:

```
update your_table
set dob = regexp_replace(dob, '(\d{4})\d{2}(\d{2})', E'\\1\\2');
```

The regex pattern being used here is:

```
(\d{4})\d{2}(\d{2})
 ^^^^        ^^^^     <-- capture groups
```

The first four and last two digits are captured in groups 1 and 2, respectively.  Then, we simply replace with the first and second capture group.

It is not clear whether the `dob` column is text or not.  If it is numeric, then you should be able to cast to text and run the above query.

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for your effort. i have edited my question. i want update query

Comment: @Curious I updated my answer, but a lingering fear is that your `dob` column is numeric.  If so, then to update as you want you would need to do a double cast.  I won't update my answer further unless you tell us this is the case.  In any event, I would argue that column should really be text anyway.

Comment: my dob field is character varying

Comment: its giving error
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 2: set dob1= regexp_replace(dob1, '(\d{4})\d{2}(\d{2})', E'\\1\...
                                       ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'

Comment: @Curious Try using this: `regexp_replace(dob, '(\d{4})\d{2}(\d{2})', E'\1\2')` ... i.e. single backslashes for the capture groups.  I simply used the Postgres documentation as a pattern for my answer, I'm surprised there are warning at all.

Comment: still i am getting the same error. however your logic and answer is exactly right to what i asked. its just having some type error. i am figuring it out.

Comment: My last guess, try double backslash everywhere: `regexp_replace(dob, '(\\d{4})\\d{2}(\\d{2})', E'\\1\\2')` ... the thing is that I don't have access to actual Postgres, only the demo, which has no warning messages.

Comment: still WARNING:  nonstandard use of \\ in a string literal